# C send broadcast. Need modify IP source field

Tags: c, ip-address, send, broadcast

I need to do the next.

I'm doing for my final degree project some sniffer in C running in openwrt firmware. I've already done every but I have one thing left I don't know how to start with.

I've the next private net: http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/999/sinttulo2de.png

What my sniffer does is to sniff all packets running through my router, and when one of these packets goes to any of my connected PCs, if that PC is asleep, it wakes it up. As if it were an automatic wake on lan.

So, I've a problem. Supposing PC3 sends a packet to PC4, the arp table from the switch knows where is PC4, and will guide that packet to the PC4 gateway. If this happens, my sniffer will never see that packet, because the sniffer is running in the proccessor in the router, and can only see the packets which go through it.

I need to do the next. When PC4 fells asleep and my sniffer detects it (already done that), the sniffers has to send a fake broadcast with the IP address source fro PC4, to cheat the switch and make it think PC4 is now connect in the gateway which goes to the router. So, the next packet which will be sent from PC3 to PC4 will go to the router instead to PC4, and my sniffer will see it.

I hope you've understand me. Sorry for my english.

Comment: To my opinion, if it does not go through the router, don't sniff it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "[Gratuitous ARP](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Gratuitous_ARP)".

I found a c implementation [here](http://ex-parrot.com/~chris/tmp/20061222/gratuitousarp.c).

But again, to my opinion, if it does not go through your router, don't sniff it.

Comment: I don't share that opinion – the router in that case is just a transparent wake-on-lan provider. Could be a separate device too. It requires though to spoof the ARP of the device which was originally adressed.

Comment: hi!! thank you, I'll take a  look in gratouis ARP. I also was told to create a broadcast packet from a raw socket. But any idea, so the only I have in your answer. Thank you. I'll write back here if I'm able to do something.

Comment: I really need to sniff that because of the reason Jonas Wielicki says.